# Pass linq to entities query as parameter and execute against different objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm looking to implement a cache so that I check to see if specific queries have been executed already, and if they have, return the data using the in memory cache. Rather than implement the cache itself, I can make use of the in memory view that EntityFramework exposes through the Local property of the DBSet.

So, I want to pass the entire query to a method that will run it against the database and/or the in memory cache. However, I'm getting my Expression/Func/IQueryable mixed up and can't see out how to pass the query/expression:

So the base class would be something like this (this obviously isn't working yet...):

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Entities _context; //instantiated in the constructor

    protected List<TEntity> GetData<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> query)
    {
        if (!HasQueryExecuted(query))
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Select(query).Load();
            AddQueryToExecutedList(query); 
        }
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Local.AsQueryable().Select(query).ToList();
    }
}
```

And I would have multiple classes that define their queries something like this:

```
public class CustomersService : ServiceBase<Customer>
{
    public List<Customer> GetCustomersWithOrders()
    {
        return GetData(c => c.Where(c => c.OrderCount > 0));
    }

    public List<Customer> GetLargestCustomersByOrder(int TopCount)
    {
        return GetData(c => c.OrderBy(c=>c.OrderCount).Take(TopCount));
    }
}
public class ProductsService : ServiceBase<Product>
{
    public List<Customer> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return GetData(p => p);
    }
    public List<Customer> GetMostOrderedProducts(int minimumOrders)
    {
        return GetData(p => p.Where(p=> p.OrderCount > minimumOrders)
                   .OrderByDescending(p=>p.OrderCount));
    }

    public List<Customer> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return GetData(p => p);
    }
}
```

These are just contrived examples, but the point is the queries could be varied, not just limited to a where clause but making use of all the standard extension methods on IQueryable to query the underlying data.

First of all, is this possible? Can the GetData method define a parameter that can take any query? With the above example, I declared the `query` parameter to accept the same type as specified for the IQueryable extension Select method, but when I try and call it with a simple Where clause or OrderBy clause, I get various compilation errors such as :

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'Entities.Customer*

or

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to 'Entities.Customer'*

And yet, it compiles just fine if I run the same query directly against the context. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is this `Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> query`

Simply put you are saying that your expression is a function type that takes a `TEntity` and returns a `TEntity`. Since your class is typed with `Entities.Customer` it will expect a function that takes an `Entities.Customer` and returns an `Entities.Customer`.

If you look at your services classes `p => p` will work fine but `p => p.Where()` will not because `Where` returns an IEnumerable.

I think you should take a different approach and take advantage of lazy-loading.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetData<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>();
}

public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllProducts()
{
    return GetData();
}

public IQueryable<Customer> GetMostOrderedProducts(int minimumOrders)
{
    return GetData().Where(p => p.OrderCount > minimumOrders)
        .OrderByDescending(p=>p.OrderCount));
}
```

You don't need to build the query into `GetData` because the query can be built at any point up until it's evaluated. If you really wanted you could return `List<T>` from here but you shouldn't really have to.

Otherwise this should do the trick for your current code.

```
protected List<TEntity> GetData<TEntity>(Func<IEnumerable<TEntity>,
                                         IEnumerable<TEntity>> query) where TEntity : class
{
    if (!HasQueryExecuted(query))
    {  
        AddQueryToExecutedList(query); 
        return query(_context.Set<TEntity>()).ToList();
    }
    return query(_context.Set<TEntity>().Local).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a for answering @Shoe.  I realise that query parameter is at fault, but it is needed to determine if the query has already been executed, in order to then run it against the database or, the Local property (in memory cache).

Comment: I understand what you're going for but lets think. Your caching the queries to save on performance (hopefully compiling them too) but compared to executing the query it is not that much time saved because the results aren't cached. What about a multi-user environment? Running a query locally could give you different results than if you ran it against the DB because of edits/updates/deletes. Your context objects should be short lived, so your local cache shouldn't get that large. Whenever you new up a context your local caches are empty, so you will have to rebuild your query cache every time.

Comment: Agreed @Shoe that is a common way of using the context.  This particular usage is slightly different, working with a snapshot of data - there are no other edits (except those made by the user which will remain in memory and will not be persisted back to the db). The context in this situation is effectively being used as a cache, hence I am looking to effectively leverage the in memory data.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @Shoe, I understand now.